# deleting unsigned char* buffer

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, native

I am currently trying to delete the buffer returned by cocos2dx but its crashing here is my code 
i am getting file data from cocos2dx and then saving its pointer after that i am adding null character at the end now when i try to delete this buffer project crashes

```
unsigned long fSize = 0;

unsigned char* pBuff =  (cocos2d::CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData(szName, "r", &fSize));

int result = 0;
if(pBuff)
{
    result = 1;
    pBuff[fSize] = '\0';
}
delete pBuff; //crashing at this line
```

implementation of getFileData is

```
unsigned char* CCFileUtils::getFileData(const char* pszFileName, const char* pszMode,       
unsigned long * pSize)
{
   unsigned char * pBuffer = NULL;
   CCAssert(pszFileName != NULL && pSize != NULL && pszMode != NULL, "Invalid parameters.");
  *pSize = 0;
  do
 {
    // read the file from hardware
    std::string fullPath = fullPathForFilename(pszFileName);
    FILE *fp = fopen(fullPath.c_str(), pszMode);
    CC_BREAK_IF(!fp);

    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    *pSize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
    pBuffer = new unsigned char[*pSize];
    *pSize = fread(pBuffer,sizeof(unsigned char), *pSize,fp);
    fclose(fp);
} while (0);

if (! pBuffer)
{
    std::string msg = "Get data from file(";
    msg.append(pszFileName).append(") failed!");

    CCLOG("%s", msg.c_str());
}
return pBuffer;
```

}

**EDIT: after changing (as suggested by David)**

```
if(pBuff)
{
    result = 1;
    pBuff[fSize] = '\0';
}
delete pBuff; //crashing at this line
```

to

```
if(pBuff)
{
    result = 1;
    //pBuff[fSize] = '\0';
    delete[] pBuff; //still crashing at this line
}
```

its still crashing

Comment: `pBuff[fSize] = '\0';` is out of range. I think, returning allocated memory is bad design (use a std::shared_ptr/std::unique_ptr instead). The `do ... while(0)`is pointless (just use `{ ... }`)

Comment: @DieterLücking that's what I thought, but the OP is kinda lucky that just adding one nul char actually generated a fault?  If it was me, I can guarantee that it would work in testing and generate intermittent faults after delivery:)

Comment: getFileData code is from cocos2dx game engine.
removing pBuff[fSize] = '\0' and using delete[] pBuff did not resolve the issue i have updated my post anyway

Comment: I rolled back your update which completely changed the question. Feel free to *add* in an update, but don't remove the original.

Comment: thanks David Heffernan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing beyond the end of the buffer here:

```
pBuff[fSize] = '\0';
```

Your call to `delete` is wrong. It needs to match the call to `new`.

```
delete[] pBuff;
```

Personally I don't see why you would use raw memory allocations here. Wouldn't it be better to use a standard container, `std::vector<unsigned char>` in this case. Or if for some reason you have to use raw memory allocation then at least wrap the memory up in a smart pointer.

---

You say that after fixing these problems, your code still fails of the `delete`. That sounds like you have corrupted the heap elsewhere.

Comment: its still crashing after the changes you have suggested

Comment: getfiledata code is not mine its from cocos2dx game engine

Comment: You are probably corrupting the heap somewhere else.

Comment: nope this is exactly the point if i comment out this code then game runs fine

Comment: "You are also calling `delete` on potentially a null pointer." - which is allowed. There's no need to check the pointer first.